# New to R...what am I doing wrong with this calculation?

Tags: r

I have no idea why R Studio has difficulties here... Any ideas?

```
#our first calculations 
quarter_1_sales <- 35657.98
quarter_2_sales <- 43810.55
midyear_sales <- quarter_1_sales + quarter_2_sales
```

Comment: It looks fine to me... did you maybe mean to have R output the value of `midyear_sales`? (If so, add a fourth line that's just `midyear_sales` to your code.)

Comment: Note: RStudio is just an IDE. If anything goes wrong, most of the time it is R's fault (the language), not the IDE!

Comment: What exactly is the difficulty? Are you getting an error message or something? It's unclear to me what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `print(midyear_sales)`

```
#our first calculations 
quarter_1_sales <- 35657.98
quarter_2_sales <- 43810.55
midyear_sales <- quarter_1_sales + quarter_2_sales

print(midyear_sales)

# or just type

midyear_sales
```

Comment: Thank you everyone.  I am clearly new and thank you for your patience and help!